# Why are my exported illustrator graphics blurry and messy in-game when scaling?

Tags: graphics, art

Non-scaled image:

[image]

And this is 2x-scaled:

[image]

I use 300dpi and did tick anti-aliasing settings for export png-24 image for my game in illustrator. But it look still bizzard when scaling. Could you please tell me what's wrong here??

What is the best way to get better art in my case?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think this would be better suited for: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: DPI has no bearing on bitmap exports. It will affect the scaling of the graphic when placed in a document, but the graphic itself is always comprised of a finite number of pixels. So when working for games, only the pixel dimensions matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scaling up any bitmapped image such as png will always look pixelated. To avoid this, if you have the memory, save the non-scaled image twice the size you currently have now and scale down 50% to get it looking like the non-scale image in the above diagram. To get it looking crisp at 2x-scale, you don't scale at all because it is already at that size.

Your other option is to use vectors, but this can become expensive in terms of consuming processing time and may lack finer details compared to bitmap, i.e. look cartoony but that could be a positive on your game. You also need to find an appropriate library to do this. The advantage of using vectors is that it will most likely take up less memory and will look good, as long as it isn't too tiny, at any scale compared to using bitmaps.

Comment: vector is not good at all for memory:((. And scale down is a good option:D.

Comment: To elaborate on this answer: when you scale up 4096 pixels into 16384 pixels, the scaling algorithm has to invent those extra 12288 pixel values based on the existing 4096. It doesn't know about the actual shape you created, only the pixels you exported. So you want to avoid needing to scale graphics up if quality is a concern.